# Same pointer different values, in multi file main package

Tags: go, pointers, dereference

My project is a login-register web server that consists of multiple files and uses another package in which the `Manager` struct is defined.

Overview of my files:

```
my-package/
       main.go
       handlers.go
       ...
```

I have a variable: `var M *Manager` declared in `main.go` before definition of `main()` and it is assigned inside `main()`:

```
var M *Manager

func main() {
  ...
  M = InitManager(...)
  ...
}
```

`handleLogin(...)` and `handleRegister(...)` are functions defined in `handlers.go` that use the `M` variable:

```
func handleRegister(...){
  ...
  fmt.Println("M:", M)
  M.Log1("logging informations...")
  ...
}


func handleLogin(...) {
  ...
  fmt.Println("M:", M)
  M.GetAccount(login)
  ...
}
```

When I go to `/login`or `/register` and the appropriate handle function is triggered it displays: `M: <nil>`

To find out something more I modified `main()` as shown below:

```
var M *Manager

func main() {
  ...
  go func() {  // for debugging
    for {
      fmt.Println("main() goloop1: M:", M)
      time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
    }
  }()

  M = InitManager(...)

  go func() {  // for debugging
    for {
      fmt.Println("main() goloop2: M:", M)
      time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
    }
  }()
  ...
}
```

and the output:

```
main() goloop2: M: &{...data as expected...}
main() goloop1: M: <nil>
main() goloop2: M: &{...data as expected...}
main() goloop1: M: <nil>
...
```

My question are:

1. How do pointers work then if one pointer gives out two values?
2. How to fix my issue and properly plan code (if that was the cause) to avoid this in future?

Comment: No variable is safe for concurrent use. Your "modified", debugging example reads / writes `M` from multiple goroutines without synchronization: data race, undefined behavior.

Comment: It's also possible this is the same reason my your original example doesn't work. Handlers run in their own goroutines, reading `M` and you modify `M` in the `main` goroutine. To overcome this, use synchronziation. If you only write `M` once, on startup, do it in the package `init()` function so no synchronization is needed (package `init()` will run before the handlers).

Comment: I declare M before init and main and assign it in init() but now main() sees it as <nil>.  What should I use to synchronize the M, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem), the provided code writes and reads `M` without proper synchronization, which is a data race and leads to undefined behavior (see icza's comment).

The compiler "assumes" that the code is properly synchronized (this is the responsibility of the developer) and so it is "allowed" to assume that `M` is never modified inside the infinite loops, so it may use a copy in a given register or stack memory location over and over, leading to the surprising output.

You may use a [sync.Mutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) to protect every access to the global `*Manager` variable `M`, as in this [modified code](https://play.golang.org/p/lK1uUKRHBU2).

Also beware of variable shadowing! It is possible to write `M := f()` instead of `M = f()`, resulting in an unrelated local variable, not affecting the global variable.

Comment: After reading _Go Memory Model_ it is still unclear to me what am I supposed to do, as this article emphasizes that first a value is assigned and then it is read, but that is most certainly what is happening in my code. 1. Declaration, 2. Assignment, 3. ListenAndServe, 4. M.Function() is called.

Comment: *not in the modified `main()`

Comment: @KacperKwaśny I updated my answer to add actionable guidance with a Mutex. However the root cause of your bug might be anywhere in the code, so it would be useful if your could share the full code (I understand this is not always possible).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I have added `init.go`:

```
my-package/
       main.go
       handlers.go
       ...
       init.go
```

I moved global variables like `M` and `CONFIG_MAP` into the `init.go` file:

```
package main

import ...

var CONFIG_MAP = LoadConfig()
var M *asrv.Manager = InitManager()

func LoadConfig() map[string]string {
    // return map from 'conf.json' file
}

func InitManager() *asrv.Manager {
    // return Manager configured with CONFIG_MAP
    // other functions also use CONFIG_MAP that is the reason why it is global
}

func init() {
    LoadTemplatesFiles() // load templates and assign value
                         // to a variable declared in templates.go
}
```

This way handler functions (`handleLoginGet` etc.) in `handlers.go` could properly read `M`.

This fix just made my program work and I still don't know what is the proper way of handling this type of situation, that is why I added more info under ***EDIT*** in my question.